# How can I make all 4 corners of my div have resizable handles with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable, jquery-ui-resizable, jquery-resizable

I am trying to append a div onClick that is both draggable and resizable with handles for resizing that div being in all 4 corners.

I have been able to make the div draggable and add the handles... HOWEVER... Only the bottom, right, and bottom-right-corners of the div actually work... the top and other corners show an arrow on hover... but won't resize the div!?!?!

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    //onClick append a resizable & draggable div with handles on all 4 corners
    $('#mega_wrap').click(function(e){

        //Define element css and positioning then add both draggable and resizable from jQuery UI
        var ele = $("<div>");
            ele.css({width:"100px", height:"100px", border:"3px dashed white", position:"absolute", left: e.pageX - 50, top: e.pageY -50});
            ele.draggable();
            ele.resizable();

        //Define elements handles and append them to the new div
        var eleHandleNE = $("<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne' id='negrip'>");
        var eleHandleSE = $("<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se' id='segrip'>");
        var eleHandleSW = $("<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw' id='swgrip'>");
        var eleHandleNW = $("<div class='ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw' id='nwgrip'>");

            eleHandleNE.appendTo(ele);
            eleHandleSE.appendTo(ele);
            eleHandleSW.appendTo(ele);
            eleHandleNW.appendTo(ele);

        //Append new div to the container div called mega_wrap
        $("#mega_wrap").append(ele);

   }); 
});

</script>

<div id="mega_wrap">
    <form class="form-wrapper cf">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Looking for inspiration..." required>
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use the handles option? http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is the way to put handles. There is no need to append `handles` explicitly.

```
    ele.resizable({
       handles: 'n, e, s, w'
    });
```

See [jQuery resizable handles](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles)

Comment: And for the corners as well you need: `handles:'all'`. Individual corners with `ne`, etc.

Comment: Or maybe `handles: 'n, e, s, w, se, ne, sw, nw'`.